# String matching in GDB

Tags: python, gdb, pretty-print

I have to write a python code which runs on a c++ code and does the string match. It should get me all the contents(address and more) of the string; matching the string I supply through my .py code. It should also do partial matches. E.g: If I give "app" as input to match, I should be able to retrieve anything which has app like apple,application etc., Once I have my contents retrieved, I should be able to print them using pretty printer.

Also it would be helpful if someone can tell me how do I pass the string to match from command line in GDB.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it compare to the expected output? We strive to teach, not just to supply.

Comment: @Delioth: 
I needed a head start as I am new to Python and GDB stuff. I wrote a simple c++ code which has objects(instances), Then I wrote a python code which has something code like the below: 
def getstr(str):
noAssertSymbol = gdb.lookup_symbol(str)
if (assertSymbol[0]):
 return assertSymbol[0].value()
else:
 print ("%s Instance not found" %(str))
return 0
//Wanted to test from command prompt in GDB but it says no val in the current context
set val = getstr(foo)
print $val
Also, I can use something like info types for partial match but it seems not working

Comment: This *really* sounds like more than one question. Implement `gdb.Command` first, call `gdb.parse_and_eval` (or possibly `gdb.Frame.read_var`) to inspect expressions. *Then*, figure out what you need to do with you `gdb.Value`s.